# Faster-RCNN bbox/image normalization

Tags: deep-learning, normalization, caffe, pycaffe

I am playing with py-faster-rcnn on a custom dataset (about 3000 images, 7 different classes, including the background), and following these tutorials:

https://github.com/zeyuanxy/fast-rcnn/blob/master/help/train/README.md (Fast-RCNN tutorial)
https://github.com/deboc/py-faster-rcnn/tree/master/help (Faster-RCNN tutorial)

I am using the end2end solution with VGG16 network.
Everything works fine, expect my results so I have some questions:

- What kind of normalizations are needed on the images and on the bbox annotations?
- It is similar to the previous question: There are two config options: BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS and BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS_PRECOMPUTED. Should I calculate the mean and std before the training and use these options for bbox normalization?
- I modified the num_output at the cls_score and bbox_pred layers (according to this thread: https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/1), but in the end2end solution there are rpn_cls_score and rpn_bbox_pred layers too. Should I modify the num_outputs of these too? If I should then how could I calculate the number of outputs for 7 classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not need to pre-compute anything. In lib/roi_data_layer/roidb.py, it computes the mean and standard deviation for your dataset if you set the BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS_PRECOMPUTED to False, otherwise, it will use the default values which are specified in lib/fast_rcnn/config.py. RPN is agnostic to number of classes. It only treats regions which contain any object as positive and everything else as negative.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to set the BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS_PRECOMPUTED to false but it caused an assertion error: 
"File "/home/spirit/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 35, in __init__
    assert cfg.TRAIN.BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS_PRECOMPUTED
AssertionError"

Comment: I looked into the code, where the assertion happens and there is a comment: "# RPN can only use precomputed normalization because there are no
            # fixed statistics to compute a priori"

Comment: I think you set BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS to False, which should be true. Anyways, these things are not needed for RPN (its only needed when you have region proposals from some other algorithm, like selective search). It would work even if you comment out all the normalization code. All the normalization for faster-rcnn is done inside generate_anchors, anchor_target_layer for training RPN and proposal_target_layer and proposal_layer for training the detector. These files are in the RPN folder.

Comment: I guess the stds and means for RPN specify the prior statistics of the proposed boxes? Then it doesn't make much sense to initialize these values according to certain data set.

Comment: I found this part (the `BBOX_NORMALIZE_STDS` and `BBOX_NORMALIZE_MEANS`) is not mentioned in the original paper. Why is it helpful?